# how to print a list vertically python

Tags: python-2.7

```
>list1=[1,2,3,4]
>list2=[5,6,7,8]
>list3=[9,10,11,12]
>list4=[13,14,15,16]
>list5=[17,18,19,20]
>lists=[list1,list2,list3,list4,list5
```

I want to print the following code so that it outputs this way:

```
4 8 12 16 20
3 7 11 15 19
2 6 10 14 18
```

sorry didn't knew it ignored new lines:

[image]

```
1 5 9  13 17
```

Thanks in advance (new to python)

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry i uploaded an image to represent it , i want it to be displayed as columns, vertically, i know that to print it as lines i do:
for i in lists:
 print i

Comment: Ugly solution but just for fun: `print(sum(zip(*[l[::-1] for l in lists]),()))`

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve this is to zip up the reversed lists and simply print all the elements out.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[5,6,7,8]
list3=[9,10,11,12]
list4=[13,14,15,16]
list5=[17,18,19,20]

for l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 in zip(reversed(list1), reversed(list2), reversed(list3), reversed(list4), reversed(list5)):
    print(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, end=' ')
```

output

```
    4 8 12 16 20 3 7 11 15 19 2 6 10 14 18 1 5 9 13 17
```

Comment: To make it print in columns you can remove the 'end' parameter